# how to use CSS positioning in 100% width layout

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I've looked through other answers on this site but am not able to find exactly what I need. I'm building a site which uses width as percentages on divs and tables. I figured this would help me keep the layout of the site static no matter what screen resolution the viewer is using. However, I notice that when I resize my window, 2 things are happening that I don't want:

1) The text elements are jumping to new lines and throwing off the whole layout. I'd really like to keep it from doing that but not sure if that goes against using the percentage thing.

2) I've used absolute positioning on some elements because they didn't really work in a table format (specifically the skills and languages portion on the right hand side--see screenshot below). But if I resize the window, they don't stay with everything else.. they just stay in one place. And I know that's what they're supposed to do but I'm just wondering if there's a way to get it to stay with everything else when resized and still be absolute (or fixed? static?).

The reason why I'm using percentages for width is because I want my site to fill the screen based on the resolution but also keep all content centered in the middle of that screen. If I resize the window, everything gets screwed up and even a nav bar which is floated to the right ends up on the other side of the screen over my logo. It's incredibly frustrating.

I don't know what the answer is but here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18U4u.jpg) of how the page looks on my browser (i.e. how it's supposed to look) and my code (below). I'd really appreciate any insight people can give me into how I should better design this site. I can't seem to do everything I want it to do and I know it's probably way simpler than I'm making it. Please let me know what you think. Thanks!

Pooja

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Pooja's Designs :: Resume</title>
<style type="text/css">
body#home {
text-align:center;
margin:0px; 
padding:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
font-family:Open Sans;
}

body#home a#nav-home,
body#resume a#nav-resume,
body#portfolio a#nav-portfolio,
body#contact a#nav-contact
{
color: #dfadec;
text-decoration:none;
}

#container {
background-color:#eae5e5;
width:100%;
text-align:left;
margin: 0 auto;
height:auto;
}

#main {
padding-top:40px !important;
padding-bottom:35px !important;
width:50%;
margin: 0 auto;
color:#4d4d4f;
}

#header {
border-top:solid 15px #4d4d4f;
font-size:30px;
color:#4d4d4f;
background-color:#FFF;
width:100%;
padding-bottom:45px;
}

#title {
padding-top:30px;
}

#footer {
color:#FFF;
font-size:12px;
background-color:#dfadec;
width:100%;
padding-bottom:45px;
padding-top:45px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100%;
border-top:solid white 3px;
}

#nav {
font-size:12px;
color:#CCC;
float:right;
margin-top:-18px;
}

#nav a:link {
color:#CCC;
text-decoration:none;
}

#nav a:hover {
color:#dfadec;
text-decoration:none;
}

#nav a:visited {
color:#CCC;
text-decoration:none;
}

h1 {
font-size:60px;
color:#4d4d4f;
margin-top:-150px;
}

h2 {
font-size:40px;
color:#4d4d4f;
font-weight:normal;
margin-top:-40px;
}

#resume-title {
color:#FFF;
letter-spacing:5px;
font-size:70px;
}

img#icon {
background-color:#4d4d4f; 
padding:12px;
}

#prof_info {
width:115px;
height:115px;
background-color:#dfadec;
margin-top:30px;
}

#prof_info p {
color:#FFF;
font-size:16px;
padding-left:10px;
letter-spacing:0px;
vertical-align:middle;
padding-top:37px;
font-weight:600;
}

#work_exp {
width:115px;
height:115px;
background-color:#dfadec;
margin-top:30px;
}

#work_exp p {
color:#FFF;
font-size:16px;
padding-left:10px;
letter-spacing:0px;
vertical-align:middle;
padding-top:37px;
font-weight:600;
}

#education {
width:115px;
height:115px;
background-color:#dfadec;
margin-top:30px;
}

#education p {
color:#FFF;
font-size:16px;
padding-left:10px;
letter-spacing:0px;
vertical-align:middle;
padding-top:47px;
font-weight:600;
}

#contact {
width:45%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#title-nav {
width:50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.position {
font-size:14px;
font-weight:600;
}

ul {
margin:0;
padding:0;
padding-left:20px;
}


ul li {
color:#dfadec;
}

</style>
</head>

<body id="home">
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<div id="title-nav">
<div id="title">
<strong>Pooja's Designs</strong><br />
<span style="font-size:16px; color:#dfadec;">Web Development / Design</span>
</div>
<div id="nav">
<strong><a href="http://www.poojasdesigns.com/" id="nav-  
home">HOME</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.poojasdesigns.com/resume" 
id="nav-resume">RESUME</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a 
href="http://www.poojasdesigns.com/portfolio" id="nav-    
portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a 
href="http://www.poojasdesigns.com/contact" id="nav-contact">CONTACT</a></strong>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="main">
<div id="resume-title">
RESUME
</div>
<div style="border-bottom:solid #999 1px; width:72%; height:5px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 1040px; top: 273px;">
<img id="icon" src="exclamation.png" style="padding-left:17px; padding-right:17px;
padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:8px; background-color:#dfadec; vertical-align:middle; 
margin-bottom:5px;" /><br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;Skills
<div style="border-bottom:solid #999 1px; width:200px; height:5px; margin
-bottom:15px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-size:12px;">DREAMWEAVER<br />
PHOTOSHOP<br />
ILLUSTRATOR<br />
FLASH<br />
INDESIGN</span>
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; left: 1038px; top: 477px;">
<img id="icon" src="globe.png" style="padding:6px; padding-left:5px; background-
color:#dfadec; vertical-align:middle; margin-bottom:5px;" /><br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;Languages
<div style="border-bottom:solid #999 1px; width:200px; height:5px; margin-   
bottom:15px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-size:12px;">HTML<br />
CSS<br />
JAVASCRIPT<br />
JQUERY<br />
PHP</span>
</div>
<table width="70%">
<tr>
<td>
<div id="prof_info">
<p>Professional<br />
info</p>
</div>
</td>
<td style="padding-left:20px; font-size:12px; text-align:justify; line-height:18px;" 
valign="bottom">
My objective is to secure the position of Web Developer/Designer in an established   
organization which will enable me to use my talents, creativity and ability to the    
maximum, and contribute to the growth of the organization, as well as myself. I am
fluent in English and Hindi, with some basic knowledge of Spanish.
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div style="border-bottom:solid #999 1px; width:72%; height:5px; padding-   
top:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
<table width="70%">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<div id="work_exp">
<p>Work<br />
experience</p>
</div>
</td>
<td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:60px; font-size:12px; text-align:justify;
line-height:18px;">
<span class="position">Web Producer | Random House, Inc<br />
2011 - present</span><br /><br />
<ul>
<li><span style="color:#4d4d4f;">Create and manage content on the AtRandom website, as  
well as author and imprint websites</span></li>
<li><span style="color:#4d4d4f;">Compile, code, and send out email newsletters (web and
mobile-responsive) using Emailvision, ExactTarget, and MailChimp</span></li>
<li><span style="color:#4d4d4f;">Manage email distribution lists (importing and
exporting subscribers)</span></li>
<li><span style="color:#4d4d4f;">Carry out website-related requests for colleagues, such
as uploading graphics to the live server and making changes to websites as
needed</span></li>
<li><span style="color:#4d4d4f;">Pull reports from Google Analytics and Omniture Site
Catalyst for newsletters and websites</span></li>
<li><span style="color:#4d4d4f;">Create and edit PDF documents of book excerpts to be
uploaded on Scribd</span></li>
<li><span style="color:#4d4d4f;">Upload book trailers to YouTube</span></li>
<li><span style="color:#4d4d4f;">Create giveaways on LibraryThing</span></li>
<li><span style="color:#4d4d4f;">Compile Google forms for giveaways and
contests</span></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div style="border-bottom:solid #999 1px; width:72%; height:5px; padding-   
top:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
<table width="56%">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<div id="education">
<p>Education</p>
</div>
</td>
<td style="padding-top:60px; font-size:12px; text-align:justify; line-height:18px;">
<span class="position">American Sentinel University<br />
2008 - 2010</span><br /><br />
Bachelor of Science, Web Design &amp; Development<br /><br />

<span class="position">University of Kentucky<br />
2005 - 2007</span><br /><br />
General Studies
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<div id="contact">
<table width="100%" style="padding-left:10px;">
<tr>
<td>
<img id="icon" src="mail-icon.png" />
</td>
<td>
<strong>Contact</strong><br />
myemail at gmail dot com
</td>
<td>
<img id="icon" src="add-icon.png" />
</td>
<td style="padding-right:25px;">
<strong>Follow me</strong><br />
<a href="" target="_blank"><img
src="Pace_Social_Icon_Set/PNG/facebook.png" width="25" border="0" style="margin-left:-
8px;" /></a><a href="" target="_blank"><img    
src="Pace_Social_Icon_Set/PNG/twitter.png" width="25" border="0" /></a><a
href="" target="_blank"><img
src="Pace_Social_Icon_Set/PNG/linkedin.png" width="30" border="0" /></a>
</td>
<td>
<img id="icon" src="call-icon.png" style="padding:8px; padding-left:12px; padding-
right:12px;" />
</td>
<td>
<strong>Call</strong><br />
C: 123.456.7890
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, if you are going to provide code you should format it. Also it will be good to create a jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: Your two issues are fairly incompatible with a fluid / stretchy layout.  The text is going to wrap / change heights as you stretch / shrink.  And, other elements are going to move around the position:absolute element, unless you get it in the right "container" that has position: relative on it.

Comment: why you are not using HTML5? <!doctype html>

Comment: You should check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for a better response on your request for a code review.

Comment: Michal, not all browsers support HTML 5 and I have not studied it sufficiently to use it.. I plan to, but for now I am using what I know already.

How did I not format the code properly? I pasted it in as is.. not sure what else I should do.

Comment: cale_b: If I don't make the tables and divs have a width in percentages but instead specify pixels, would that still work if the #container div and body have a 100% width? and would that prevent the paragraphs from resizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key concept for building responsive layouts is Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning. Chris Coyier has a great article here: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/. This concept allows you to position items absolutely inside a relatively position element.

I've applied this concept to your code so you can start to get the idea of what I'm talking about. However, with all the tables and inline styles, your markup still needs some major refactoring. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/meub/4pcx5/4/

Some key code in the fiddle:

```
#main {
padding-top:40px !important;
padding-bottom:35px !important;
width: 830px;
margin: 0 auto;
color:#4d4d4f;
 /* Important! Lets you position elements absolutely INSIDE this div */
 position: relative;
}
```

Some other important lessons to make your life easier in the future:

- Don't use inline styles
- Don't use tables for layout
- Indent your code so it's easier to read ([this](http://www.dirtymarkup.com/) is a good tool for messy code)

Comment: Wow thanks so much for this! It's extremely helpful. If I use max-width of 830px then will that expand the body, container, main and footer sections to fill the screen without affecting the content inside them? That's what I wanted to achieve but seems it's difficult to do so. Or would I have to do a media query for that? I didn't really want to do that as I don't have a lot of experience with it but will do so if it's necessary to what I was trying to achieve. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Sorry for that previous question.. I just tried it and indeed it does accomplish what I was trying to do so thanks for that! I now have the issue that if I make the window smaller, the header, paragraphs, nav bar, etc all move around and overlap each other. Is there any way to stop it from doing that? I just want everything to stay in one place even if the window is made smaller.

Similarly, if I add padding to position a div further to the left or right, will that throw off the layout or does it not matter now as the main and container divs have relative positioning? Please clarify. Thanks!

Comment: If you want that behavior, just use width:830px on the #title-nav and #main like this: http://jsfiddle.net/meub/4pcx5/4/

Answer (score 0):

To leave everything in the center you need the body to be something like this:

```
body{
padding: 0 0 0 0;
border:0;
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
}
```

and then you need a wrapper div, let's say:

```
.wrapper{
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
width:900px;  //modify this to the size you want 
}
```

then put everything inside that wrapper div, everything will be in the center of that wrapper div

Comment: But if I put it at 900px, then the elements don't expand to fit the browser. I want it to do that but I don't want all the text elements to change when the browser is made smaller or expanded. I want them to stay static. So how can I achieve both?